# Drawing semitransparent child window with image on parent window

Tags: winapi, animation, transparency, layered-windows, ws-ex-layered

I need to make bird animation in `WS_OVERLAPPED` window (as shown below). Animation is represented by 8 images:

[image: Animation]

The blue color in the image (which is `RGB(0, 255, 255)`) has to be transparent (see screenshot below).

I wanted to do this using `CreateWindowEx()` (bird would be represented by layered window) with `WS_EX_LAYERED` argument. Unfortunately bird must be `WS_CHILD`. Mixing `WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_CHILD` [is not legal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in **Windows 7**:

> **Windows 8:**  The **WS_EX_LAYERED** style is supported for top-level windows and child windows. Previous Windows versions support **WS_EX_LAYERED** only for top-level windows.

Final effect should look like this (I've already painted window's background - the only problem is the bird):

[image]

How can I achieve this effect? How to animate bird in parent window? 

If you have any idea how to implement bird animation with transparent background color please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally find out how to do it. It's quite tricky.

The full description of the solution is available here - [winprog.org/tutorial/transparency.html](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/transparency.html). 
For polish readers here is [great translation](http://cpp0x.pl/kursy/Kurs-WinAPI-C++/Podstawy/Bitmapy/182).

Simple idea in brief:

> Giving bitmaps the appearance of having transparent sections is quite simple, and involves the use of a black and white Mask image in addition to **the colour image that we want to look transparent**.
>   The following conditions need to be met for the effect to work correctly: First off, the colour image must be black in all areas that we want to display as transparent. And second, **the mask image must be white in the areas we want transparent**, and black elsewhere. The colour and mask images are displayed as the two left most images in the example picture on this page.

Simple solution in brief:

```
#define TRANSPARENCY_COLOR RGB(0, 255, 255)

birdBmp = (HBITMAP) LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
hbmpMask = CreateBitmapMask(birdBmp, TRANSPARENCY_COLOR);
```

Painting:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    HDC birdMaskHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

    BITMAP bmInfo;
    GetObject(birdBmp, sizeof(bmInfo), &bmInfo);

    HBITMAP hbmpOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(birdMaskHdc, hbmpMask);

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bmInfo.bmWidth, bmInfo.bmHeight, birdMaskHdc, 0, 0, SRCAND);
    SelectObject(birdMaskHdc, birdBmp);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bmInfo.bmWidth, bmInfo.bmHeight, birdMaskHdc, 0, 0, SRCPAINT);

    SelectObject(birdMaskHdc, hbmpOld);
    DeleteDC(birdMaskHdc);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

Cleaning:

```
case WM_DESTROY:
{
    DeleteObject(hbmpMask);
    DeleteObject(birdBmp);
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
}
```

Function which is responsible for creating bitmap mask:

```
HBITMAP CreateBitmapMask(HBITMAP hbmColour, COLORREF crTransparent)
{
    HDC hdcMem, hdcMem2;
    HBITMAP hbmMask, hbmOld, hbmOld2;
    BITMAP bm;

    GetObject( hbmColour, sizeof( BITMAP ), & bm );
    hbmMask = CreateBitmap( bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, 1, 1, NULL );

    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC( NULL );
    hdcMem2 = CreateCompatibleDC( NULL );

    hbmOld =( HBITMAP ) SelectObject( hdcMem, hbmColour );
    hbmOld2 =( HBITMAP ) SelectObject( hdcMem2, hbmMask );

    SetBkColor( hdcMem, crTransparent );

    BitBlt( hdcMem2, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );
    BitBlt( hdcMem, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem2, 0, 0, SRCINVERT );

    SelectObject( hdcMem, hbmOld );
    SelectObject( hdcMem2, hbmOld2 );
    DeleteDC( hdcMem );
    DeleteDC( hdcMem2 );

    return hbmMask;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since animation is done even when there's no interaction with the window, we'll need a timer:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    // load resources
    SetTimer(hwnd, 0, 250, NULL); // set timer to 250 ms
return 0;

...

case WM_DESTROY:
    KillTimer(hwnd, 0);
    // release the resources
return 0;
```

We can invalidate the whole window each timer tick, but it would be better to redraw only needed part. We'll also update the current frame number here:

```
case WM_TIMER:
    frame_number++;
    if (frame_number >= 8)
        frame_number = 0;

    RECT rc = { 30, 30, 80, 80 }; // a rectangle from (30,30) to (80,80)
    InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rc, FALSE);
return 0;
```

Then, we draw the current frame in the `WM_PAINT` handler:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    // draw the sky

    SelectObject(hDCMem, hBird);
    TransparentBlt(hDC, 30, 30, 50, 50, hDCMem, frame_number * 51, 0, 50, 50, RGB(0, 255, 255)); // 51 is 50 (side of a bird frame) + 1 (gap between the frames)

    // draw the rest
return 0;
```

Comment: I've forgot to mention that `TransparentBlt()` is forbidden in this project (I don't know why).

Comment: @patryk.beza, is `BitBlt` also forbidden? If no, you could use the Wine implementation of `TransparentBlt`: http://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/dlls/gdi32/bitblt.c#l827? If yes, how do you paint the background?

Comment: I paint background using `BitBlt` which is not forbidden.